# Ubuntu 15.04 logout delays long time

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, shutdown, logout

I've just upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 but now it has a problem when I logout. My computer delays (or freezes I don't know how to say) about one minute or more then logout.

In the first shutdown or restart after upgraded it had same delay but now shutdown and restart are fine, just within 30s. I think these are OK because I cleaned old packages and linux-generic by Blechbit and Ubuntu Tweak. I also tried fix my grub by remove "quite flash" or add "acpi=off" or "acpi=force" but nothing changed.

Hope somebody can help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I've just figure out, diodon indicator is the reason.

Comment: Answer your own question below if you think it has been solved.